# Clean up output of my script (netsh interfaces list)

Tags: batch-file, netsh

My company does not use DHCP for the computers of the employees, so I have to type everything in manually. So I thought it would be nice to write a simple script for this.

The problem is to specify the interface I want to configure. I want a little menu where I can simply select the device. The menu actually works, but the problem is that there are unnecessary spaces at the end I do not get rid off..

(`%IP%` and `%Gateway%` are defined in other logic..)

This is what I currently have:

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set /P Gateway="Welcher Gateway? "
set /P IP="Welche IP? "
echo --------------------------------
echo NR. Schnittstellenname
echo --------------------------------
SET countST=1
for /f "tokens=4-10" %%a in ('netsh interface show interface') do (
    echo !countST!.  %%a %%b %%c %%d %%e
    set /a countST+=1
    )
SET /P numberST="Welche Schnittstelle soll konfiguriert werden? (NR) "
SET countST=1
for /f "tokens=4-10" %%a in ('netsh interface show interface') do (
    if !countST!==%numberST% (
        set ST="%%a %%b %%c %%d %%e"
        )
    set /a countST+=1
    )
echo %ST%
netsh interface ipv4 set address name=%ST% static %IP% 255.255.255.0 %Gateway% store=persistent
netsh interface ipv4 set dnsservers name=%ST% source=static address="8.8.8.8" validate=no
netsh interface ipv4 add dnsservers name=%ST% address="1.1.1.1" validate=no index=2
PAUSE
endlocal
```

Answer (score 0):

I already tried something like this, but it somehow does not work:

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set countST=1
echo off
for /f "tokens=4-10" %%a in ('netsh interface show interface') do (
        if "%e%"==" " (
            if "%d%"==" " (
                if "%c%"==" " (
                    if "%b%"==" " (
                        echo %%a
                        pause
                    ) else (
                        echo %%a %%b
                        pause
                    )
                ) else (
                    echo %%a %%b %%c
                    pause
                )
            ) else (
                echo %%a %%b %%c %%d
                pause
            )
        ) else (
            echo %%a %%b %%c %%d %%e
        )
    )
    pause
```

Comment: that was the way to go. i simply had to write the if-statement like this:


`if "%%e"=="" (`

Comment: try `for /f "tokens=3,*" %%a in ('netsh interface show interface') do echo "%%b"` - should help you to shorten your code immensely.